# SSRS chart series labels: Field!axisfield.Value not current value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to dynamically format the labels on my SSRS charts based on the underlying value. I'm trying to do this in two scenarios, one to format dates as ordinals and another to choose the appropriate number of decimal places based on actual values present. However, when I use the expression editor with an expression something like this...

```
=IIF(MAX(ABS(Fields![axisfield].Value))<2, "0.0%","0%")
```

...the Fields![axisfield].Value is *always* returning the first value from the dataset, meaning, in this example, if the first value is less than two, the labels will be formatted with one decimal place, even if it is the only one less than two. (So the 'MAX' function is essentially irrelevant.)

That example is attempting to set the overall formatting based on the largest data point in the series, in this next one I'm trying to format each label separately to get Ordinal dates (i.e. 1st, 2nd, etc, and yes, this formula is incomplete: it doesn't need to be to illustrate the problem):

```
="dd"+IIF(DatePart("d", Fields!date.Value)=1,"\s\t"
,IIF(DatePart("d", Fields!date.Value)=2,"\n\d"
,IIF(DatePart("d", Fields!date.Value)=3,"\r\d"
,"\t\h")))
```

This will give 1st, 2st, 3st and so on, as the first row in the dataset is for the first.

So, my question is, how do I get round this and, in the first example get the true maximum, and in the second reference the actual value being formatted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issues with using custom functions for setting label visibility. (see my entry for this: [How to Display Only 1 Value Label in SSRS 2012 Calculated/Derived Series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165340/how-to-display-only-1-value-label-in-ssrs-2012-calculated-derived-series/37308422#37308422) )

I believe the issue is that data and fields are bound to the underlying data series but are not bound and accessible within the label itself.

You should be able to set the formatting in the function for the series data itself (as in the 2nd example) and then just set data labels, which will use the underlying series field value. An example with your data might be something like the following, which returns the values with the format:

```
="dd"+IIF(DatePart("d", Fields!date.Value)=1,Format(Fields!date.Value, "\s\t")
,IIF(DatePart("d", Fields!date.Value)=2,Format(Fields!date.Value,"\n\d")
,IIF(DatePart("d", Fields!date.Value)=3,Format(Fields!date.Value, "\r\d")
,Format(Fields!date.Value,"\t\h"))))
```

In the first example, you can get the max value to referring to the Dataset, as opposed to the field. Your code would then be:

```
=IIF(ABS(MAX(Fields![axisfield].Value, "YourDatasetName"))<2, "0.0%","0%")
```

(I changed the order of operations for Abs and Max because you have to use an aggregate function when referring to the whole dataset. Only then can you refer to the specific value.)